# warning message with new machine "font family not found in Windows database"

Tags: r

Since installing R on my new machine, I get this error when printing graphics in RStudio:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font family not found in Windows font database
```

Often it will repeat itself dozens of times at each plot device printing, and I can't print using ggsave.

I have installed the package `extrafont` to manually load fonts with different devices, without having an effect.

What's going on here? The graphic I'm producing doesn't use any font not in the windows font database.

```
> Sys.info()
          sysname           release           version          nodename           machine 
        "Windows"        ">= 8 x64"      "build 9200" "LAPTOP-NLL471BV"          "x86-64"
```

Thanks for your thoughts on this